# How to include jars into the lib or user lib android project on APK?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build, apk

I'm developing a RestFul services and I have my jar client that contains all my DTOs to communicate with the android application(client side). I can have reference to my jar client in the eclipse editor, but when I generate the APK and run the application in my emulator or my cellphone the class doesn't exist because the jar wasn't imported to the APK.

I test many things, adding the jars into the library and export them, also, I created a User Library and included all my jars into this and export that library, but neither of these work.

Anybody can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a folder called "lib" inside your eclipse project and put all your jar files in that folder.

Then. go to:

```
Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries
```

Just click into "Add JARs..." and select the jar files inside the lib folder.

Click and OK and Clean/Build your project

Comment: I tested that way but when I generate the APK and run, I got a error message that the class doesn't exist, because the class wasn't added to the APK.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to export the JAR file you are referencing if it hasn't already been added to the "Android Private Libraries" group in Eclipse.

[image: Eclipse order and export]